# Create dynamically HTML with JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Maybe the questions sounds familiar but it's not.
I want to append HTML code (many lines) after div which get value from other text fields. I am new with JS ,can sb help me to figure out how to do it with JS?
I want the same block of code creating dynamically.
I tried: `innerHTML`, `createElement` and `iframe` and it's not working (for me).

```js
function addField(){
//get value from elsewhere
var valueCategory =document.getElementById('newCateg').value;
//get value from elsewhere
  var newField=document.getElementById('newField').value;
//get value from elsewhere  
var selOption=document.option[selectedIndex.text];

var newField=document.getElementsByClassName("categories");

  
          
}
```

```html
<div class="categories">
 <p class="titles" >
 <input type="checkbox" class="check" onchange="checkAll('divID',true,elem)" /> Category Music </p>
  <hr/>
<div class="field">      
    <input type="checkbox" class="check"/>    
        <label> Rock</label>
        <input type="text" />
        </br>
</div>
      <input type="checkbox" class="check" />   
        <label>Classical </label>
        <input type="text"  id="c1" />
    </br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" />   
        <label>Rap  </label>
        <input type="text"  id="c1" />
      </br>
    <hr/>
</div>


<div class="categories">
 <p class="titles" >
 <input type="checkbox" class="check" onchange="checkAll('divID',true,elem)" />  Here gets the  new category which get VALUE from other text </p>
  <hr/>
<div class="field">      
    <input type="checkbox" class="check"/>    
        <label> Subcategory ..Here gets the  VALUE from other text</label>
        <input type="text" />
        </br>
</div>
      <input type="checkbox" class="check" />   
        <label>Subcategory...Here goes gets  VALUE from other text </label>
        <input type="text"  id="c1" />
    </br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" />   
        <label>Subcategory...Here gets the  VALUE from other text  </label>
        <input type="text"  id="c1" />
      </br>
    <hr/>
</div>
```

Comment: When using `createElement` or `innerHTML`, what exactly did not work? Those methods are fine to build dynamic HTML and I can assure you that they work. If you think you have a bug in your code, please post that code (the one with `createElement` or `innerHTML` in it…) to get help from others.

Comment: Look the comment i wrote to user @chsdk and it will help you understand what i want to say ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't really understand what do you want to achieve, but if you want to create a new field that gets the value of the others elements, try the following:

```js
function addField(){
 //Get the others fields values
  var Rock =document.getElementById("Rock").value;
  var Classical =document.getElementById("classical").value;
  var Rap =document.getElementById("Rap").value;

 //Get the div in wich you will create the new Field.
  var newField1=document.getElementById("RockCategory");
  var newField2=document.getElementById("ClassicalCategory");
  var newField3=document.getElementById("RapCategory");
 //Create the new Field and give it the others fields values.
  newField1.innerHTML="Rock: "+Rock;
  newField2.innerHTML="Classical: "+Classical;
  newField3.innerHTML="Rap: "+Rap;
}
```

```html
<div class="categories">
 <p class="titles" >
 <input type="checkbox" class="check" /> Category Music </p>
  <hr/>
<div class="field">      
 <input type="checkbox" class="check"/>    
        <label> Rock</label>
        <input type="text" id="Rock"/>
        </br>
</div>
      <input type="checkbox" class="check" />   
        <label>Classical </label>
        <input type="text"  id="classical" />
    </br>
 <input type="checkbox" class="check" />   
        <label>Rap  </label>
        <input type="text"  id="Rap" />
      </br>
 <hr/>
</div>

 <input type="button" onclick="addField()" value="AddField"/> 

<div class="categories">  
  Music Ctegories:  
  </br>
 <div id="RockCategory">
    </div>
      </br>
    <div id="ClassicalCategory">
    </div>
      </br>
    <div id="RapCategory">
    </div>
      </br>
 <hr/>
</div>
```

Comment: Alright ,i want the <div class="categories">and all the inside content to put in innerHTML as you did.The names "Category Music","Rock","Classical","Pop" will come from some <input type="text"/>

Comment: @MilsZ Well take a look at my Edit. Is that what you wnat?

Answer (score -1):

in jQuery your code should look like this:

```
$("#secondFieldId").val($("#firstFieldId").val());
```

or if you want the text to show in a div use this:

```
$("#divId").html("$("#fieldId").val());
```

if you want it to be triggered by an action lets say "keydown" on input field use this:

```
$("#inputFieldId").on("keydown", function(){
    $("#divId").html("$("#fieldId").val());
});
```

for more information about jQuery read: [jQuery site](http://jquery.com/)

Comment: this question doesn't have jQuery tag.

Comment: I saw many questions that didn't have jQuery tags but still with answers in jQuery just because they're good answers and it will be easier to accomplish with jQuery. For instance if he wants it to be updated with every click like I suggested.